# Can I re-direct an existing (entire) gnome-session's display to a remote work station?

Tags: ssh, fedora, xorg, gnome, xforwarding

So instead of using VNC for example
- I could actually run a command on my home-fedora terminal 
and have my work-fedora existing gnome-session appear at home?

Answer (score 2):

I think you use, [Vino](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vino).

> Vino is the GNOME desktop sharing server.

This (`vino`) is default package in most of the distribution along with `gnome`.

Comment: Thanks, but if i'm not mistaken vino is actually a vnc server.

Answer (score 0):

The Tiger's `x0vncserver` could help share the existing `X` server regardless of the desktop in use:

```
NAME
       x0vncserver - TigerVNC Server for X displays

SYNOPSIS
       x0vncserver [options]
       x0vncserver -version

DESCRIPTION
       x0vncserver  is a TigerVNC Server which makes any X display
       remotely accessible via VNC, TigerVNC or compatible viewers.
       Unlike Xvnc(1), it does not create a virtual display.
       Instead, it just shares an existing X server (typically, 
       that one connected to the physical screen).
```

Answer (score -1):

If you would like a secure channel, then you can use ssh.  You would need to enable X11 forwarding on both the client and server (/etc/ssh/ssh_config and /etc/ssh/sshd_config, X11Forwarding, TrustedX11Forwarding).

Comment: ssh X forwarding does not forward whole X11 session.